# what are the states and transistion matrices used in the robot_pose_ekf stack

Tags: ros, navigation, filter, kalman, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know what state vector, inputs, transistion matrix and measurement matrix is used with the robot_pose_ekf package?

The package fuses data from odometry, IMU and vo. how does this implement the ekf?I've read that you do a prediction step and then a correction step. During which step is each of the data used?

I'm trying to modify the code to incorporate a gyro, but am unable to understand the code.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38852/what-are-the-states-and-transistion-matrices-used-in-the-robot_pose_ekf-stack/) by [sethu chidam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2825/sethu-chidam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This answer might help.](http://answers.ros.org/question/42734/how-does-robot_pose_ekf-work/?answer=42765#post-id-42765)

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1